# Jquery slider with buttons

Tags: jquery, button, slider

I've got a slider that looks something like this
(note the content/image is the same image just one big image with smaller buttons to left)

Button 1 |   CONTENT/IMAGE

Button 2 |   CONTENT/IMAGE

Button 3 |   CONTENT/IMAGE

Button 4 |   CONTENT/IMAGE

With the buttons on the left and content appearing at the right, each button shows a different div. So the problem is, I need this to loop, and once a button is clicked stop the loop and just display the information. I am having quite a lot of trouble doing this though, the loop works but I cannot get the buttons to work.

NOTE: the hover section in the middle is not really needed anymore (defunct) but I've left it in and starred out incase this is somehow important to it working.

Here is my code:

```
//the variables
var i = 1;
var myTimer;

function myLoop() {
    //hide everything
    $(".nHstuff").hide();
    $(".nH").removeClass("active");
    //show just the stuff we want
    $("#nHstuff" + i).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    $("#nH" + i).addClass("active");
    //increment variables
    i++;

    if (i == 5) {
        i = 1;
    }

    //the timer      
    myTimer = setTimeout(myLoop, 5000);
}
//start the loop
myLoop();

/*//what to do if hovered over an item
$(".nH").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    // clear content
    $(".nHstuff").hide();
    $(".nH").removeClass("active");
    // show content
    $("#nHstuff" + (this.id.substr(this.id.length - 1))).show();
});

$(".nH").mouseout(function() {
    myLoop();
});*/


    clearTimeout(myTimer);
    i = this.id.substr(this.id.length - 1, 1);
    //show just the stuff we want
    $("#nHstuff" + i).show();
    $("#nH" + i).addClass("active");
    // To start looping again, call myLoop
});
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML as well?

Comment: The javascript is an incomplete fragment

Comment: the js is in a seperate file with jquery as well? and sure I will post the html in a js fiddle